# MS Access SQL find the year a value first appears

Tags: sql, ms-access, distinct

Hi I'm trying to run a query on a species database.  I want to query unique values but also find the year that species was first found.

So far I have this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Genus_HeTR] & " " & [Species_HeTR] AS Species
FROM HeTR_Rec
WHERE [Species_HeTR] <> "sp."
UNION SELECT DISTINCT [Genus_HeOP] & " " & [Species_HeOP] AS Species
FROM HeOP_Rec
WHERE [Species_HeOP] <> ""
AND [Species_HeOP] <> "sp.";
```

I'm concatenating the Genus and species name and adding data from two different tables (hence the UNION).  This provides a species list but I would like to know the year that species was seen at this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will hazard a guess that both your source tables include a Date/Time field which stores the date of each observation.  If that is so, you can `UNION` data from the 2 tables and use that as a subquery source in a `GROUP BY` query where you derive the minimum observation year for each species.

```sql
SELECT
    sub.Species,
    Min(sub.observation_year) AS first_sighting_year
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            [Genus_HeTR] & " " & [Species_HeTR] AS Species,
            Year(observation_date) AS observation_year
        FROM HeTR_Rec
        WHERE [Species_HeTR] <> "sp."
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            [Genus_HeOP] & " " & [Species_HeOP] AS Species,
            Year(observation_date) AS observation_year
        FROM HeOP_Rec
        WHERE [Species_HeOP] <> ""
        AND [Species_HeOP] <> "sp."
    ) AS sub
GROUP BY sub.Species;
```

Comment: HansDown the best.  Thanks Hans.  You were right to assume I had year in there.  However, it was held in another table (occasion is time date weather etc, records hold the individual species) I snuck round that by just making a standalone query and using that in the above code instead of the original tables.  Worked like a charm though.  Thanks again.

Comment: I got a chuckle from HansDown.  Thanks for that, Birdkin.  :-)